# How to allow using shortcodes in post box

Tags: wordpress, post, box

I think this code is responsible for don't let me use shortcodes in Peepso post box.

```
public function peepso_activity_remove_shortcode( $content )
{
    foreach($this->shortcodes as $shortcode=>$class) {
        foreach($this->shortcodes as $shortcode=>$class) {
            $from = array('['.$shortcode.']','['.$shortcode);
            $to = array('&#91;'.$shortcode.'&#93;', '&#91;'.$shortcode);
            $content = str_ireplace($from, $to, $content);
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: There's probably a good reason why the plugin doesn't allow using shortcodes. Have you tried reaching out to the developer to ask about this? If not it might be a good idea to do so: [PeepSo Support Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/peepso-core/).

Comment: I already asked them and they told me to pay developer. I am using free version, no budget for developer. Thanks.

Comment: There is fillter before code I posted

add_filter('peepso_activity_remove_shortcode', array(&$this, 'peepso_activity_remove_shortcode'));